# within a 3D binary matrix, finding the largest (volume-wise) sub matrix, that has at least X% TRUE pixels

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, matrix

I'm trying to find a general solution to the problem at the headline. here is an example:

create a 3d matrix with a large object and some change:

```
samp3D = false(200,200,200);
samp3D(10:90,10:90,10:90) = true; % create a large cube
samp3D(30:120,10:40,5:15) = true; % create x-axis projection
samp3D(80:100,40:150,40:90) = true; % create y-axis projection
samp3D(60:80,60:70,10:end) = true;samp3D(30:40,30:50,10:120) = true; % create z-axis projections
samp3D(60:90,120:150,120:150) = true;samp3D(120:150,10:40,120:150) = true; %add 2 small cubes
samp3D(randi(200*200*200,10000,1)) = true; %add some noise
```

Now, when dividing the number of TRUE indices with the number of all indices we get about 9.3%:

```
TruePercent = sum(samp3D(:))/numel(samp3D(:)); %TruePercent comes to about ~9.3%
```

What is the largest (volume-wise) sub-matrix within the 3D matrix that has TruePercent of at least 40%?

Comment: I might be wrong, but I think this problem is NP hard.

Comment: You should certainly start with the 1D version of this problem (with a binary 1D array). If we take the 1D version: to reduce the number of iteration needed you can, for example, take the full segment en check if the condition is satisfied. If not divide the segment by 2 (so we have 1/2 full segment) and check if there is at least one position that satisfied the condition. If this position exist now check for a bigger segment (3/4 of the segment or (1 + 1/2)/2), if this position does not exist divide again the segment by 2 and repeat the operation.